# GPA converter from digits to letter grade in PHP

Tags: php

I have made a PHP code to convert the GPA that is being retrieved from database as digits to a letters like A,B,C .. and so on, but all the results are F even if the GPA is equal 4.0.
This is my code tell me please what is wrong with it

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show_result))

    {
    //$data holds the array
                $row['GPA'] = $grad;
             if ($grad <= 0.9 && $grad >=0.0)
             {
                 $grad = 'F';
             }
            else if ($grad<= 1.9 && $grad >=1.0 )
            {
                $grad = 'D';
            }

             else if ($grad <= 2.9 && $grad >=2.0)
            {
                $grad = 'C'; 
            }
             else if ($grad <= 3.9 && $grad >=3.0)
      {
          $grad = 'B';
      }
      else if ($grad == 4.0)
      {
          $grad = 'A';
      }

     echo "<td>" . $grad . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$row['GPA'] = $grad;` should be `$grad=$row['GPA'];`

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't ask for a code review, but I couldn't help but make some suggestions:

Your logic for determining grades doesn't have to be interspersed with your database code, or with your html-generating code. Also, it'll be much more flexible and maintainable if the cutoff values are not woven into the logic. Maybe something like this to start:

```
/**
* Get a letter grade from a numeric GPA and a grading scale
* $scale is an array of letter grades keyed by minimum GPA cutoffs,
* and should be sorted in descending order by key (cutoff)
*/
function get_letter_grade ($numeric_grade, $scale)
{
    $letter_grade = 'F';
    foreach ($scale as $cutoff => $grade)
    {
        if ($numeric_grade >= $cutoff)
        {
            $letter_grade = $grade;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $letter_grade;
}
```

Then you can test it like so (if not with a unit testing framework):

```
$scale = array (
    4.0 => 'A',
    3.0 => 'B',
    2.0 => 'C',
    1.0 => 'D',
);
$test = 0.0;
while ($test <= 4.0)
{
    $grade = get_letter_grade ($test, $scale);
    echo "letter grade for $test is $grade\n";
    $test = round ($test + 0.1, 1);  // round to avoid floating point error
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot sir for the code review it is very interesting I might need that later on :)) but now I just fixed the problem that I faced with my code,, thank you again for that answer